# Join ekstra months to dataset sql

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, dataset

First off, thanks to anyone who helps me solve this problem. I am using SQL 2012,

I have a rows of data that look like such:

```
| myPK | Name| Month |  Value | 
   1      SB        1        500    
   2      SB        4        100
```

So what i now want is the month between a whole year (i have a date table containing all information about dates). Results should be:

```
|  Month  | Name |  Value | 
  1      SB         500
  2      SB         0        
  3      SB         0        
  4      SB         100        
  5      SB         0        
  6      SB         0
```

How do i add all the extra months i dont have in my orginal dataset?

Comment: Would your value really be 500 even though no data is present for that month? Wouldn't you want it to be 0 or NULL?

Comment: Sorry, yes i want it to be 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired results I would usually create a template dataset/query so it gives me all values I want to display in my report.

I would then `LEFT JOIN` to this template to get my values and replace any `NULL` values with 0.

```
WITH ReportTemplate AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Name
        , MonthNumber

    FROM
        MyTable
        CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                MonthNumber

            FROM
                MonthDate

            WHERE
                MonthNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 6
        ) AS Months
)
, ReportData AS
(
    SELECT
        Name
        , MonthNumber
        , SUM(Value) AS Value

    FROM
        MyTable

    GROUP BY
        Name
        , MonthNumber
)

SELECT
        t.Name
    ,   t.MonthNumber
    ,   ISNULL(d.Value, 0) AS Value

FROM
    ReportTemplate AS t
    LEFT JOIN ReportData aS d
        ON  t.Name = d.Name
            AND t.MonthNumber = d.MonthNumber
```

Comment: Sorry ! I posted too fast, so i had it in C/P, so i just changed it to my request - My bad!

Comment: Im not sure its working. It get the same result. Its like when i run the query form reporttemplate by it self it still keeps the current values i have.

Comment: Ohh i figured it out (Had to put months.MontNumber infront from reporttemplate! That worked it out! Thank u so much :)

Comment: Yes, I was about to suggest that as I didn't know the full details of your schema. Could you mark this as your answer.